# Font size of an argument which may be omitted

Tags: macros

(It is possible that this question has been asked before; I don't know how to search for it.)

Suppose I have:

```
\newcommand{\example}[3] {#1} {#2} {#3}}
```

And I know that I want the font size of the first argument to be “small”.

This:

```
\newcommand{\example}[3] \begin{small}{#1}\end{small} {#2} {#3}}
```

does it, but if the first argument is empty than I get “There's no line to end” error.

This:

```
\newcommand{\example}[3] \small{{#1}} {#2} {#3}}
```

affects the font size of the other two arguments (to “small”).

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the intended behavior?

Comment: `there's no line to end`  error comes (almost always) from `\\ ` which you don't show in your code. font size changes should always end in `\par` so `{\small #1\par}` but that won't affect the no line error which is unrelated to the size change

Comment: `\newcommand\example[3]{{\small #1} {#2} {#3}}` would be easier than inserting an environment.

Comment: The fundamental issue to keep in mind is that `\small` is a switch and *not* an environment (in the LaTeX sense of the word). To limit the scope of `\small`, either surround it with a pair of curly braces -- as @StevenB.Segletes suggests in his comment -- or use some other grouping device, such as `\begingroup\small#1\endgroup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although some kind of an answer has already been given by Steven B. Segletes, in a comment, I post this answer with a group safe change the font size and using a closing `\par` for the font change. `\par` provides better linespacings, as a font (size) change should occur in an paragraph, for typographical reasons only.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\mysupercommand}[3]{\begingroup\small #1\par\endgroup{#2} {#3}}

\begin{document}

\LARGE
\mysupercommand{First is small}{but the rest}{is not}

\mysupercommand{\blindtext}{\blindtext}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to mention explicitly that a (presumably desired!) reason for using `\par` is that the line spacing in effect for the material inside the "small" group is what's appropriate for material that's typeset in the "small" (relative) font size. If one were to use `\linebreak`, say, this happy effect would not come into play.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, as always a helpful comment by you.